Navbar not updating after login completes and user is navigated to a new page
I'm using selective rendering in my Navbar for few buttons. First I'm checking if accessToken is found in localStorage only then render those buttons, but when I login and navigate user to a new page the navbar doesn't update to show those buttons.
import React,{forwardRef, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { logoutUser } from "@/features/userSlice";
import { NavLink, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { LogOut, Settings, User, Users, Plus } from "lucide-react";
import { Avatar, AvatarFallback, AvatarImage } from "@/components/ui/avatar";
import {
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownMenuContent,
  DropdownMenuItem,
  DropdownMenuSeparator,
  DropdownMenuTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dropdown-menu";

//********************************* getting token from localStorage********************
const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
************************************************************************************

const AvatarDropdown = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <DropdownMenu modal={true} onOpenChang={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
        <DropdownMenuTrigger className="outline-none">
          <Avatar>
            <AvatarImage src="https://github.com/shadcn.png" />
            <AvatarFallback>CN</AvatarFallback>
          </Avatar>
        </DropdownMenuTrigger>
        <DropdownMenuContent align="end" className="text-center">
          <DropdownMenuItem
            onClick={() => handleLogout()}
            className="px-5 py-1 "
          >
            <LogOut className="mr-3" />
            Logout
          </DropdownMenuItem>
        </DropdownMenuContent>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </>
  );
};

const Header = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

******************tried this re-rendering method*** doesn't work******
  const [re, setRe] = useState(true);
  const user = useSelector(getUserInfo);

  useEffect(()=>{
    setRe(!re)
  },[user.accessToken])
***********************************************************************
  return (
    <main
      className="w-full bg-orange-400 h-fit md:px-[100px] px-[40px] py-2 flex items-center justify-between box-border fixed top-0 z-10"
      ref={ref}
    >
      <div className=" md:flex hidden w-[70%] items-center gap-5">
        <div className="w-full flex flex-1 items-center justify-end gap-5">
          {!token && (
            <NavLink
              className={({ isActive }) =>
                `p-2 font-semibold rounded-md bg-teal-400
                 text-white hover:bg-teal-500 active:bg-teal-700
                 ${isActive ? "border-[2px]" : ""}`
              }
              to="/register-login"
            >
              Register / Login
            </NavLink>
          )}
          <NavLink
            className={({ isActive }) =>
              `p-2 font-semibold rounded-md bg-indigo-400
               text-white hover:bg-indigo-500 active:bg-indigo-700
               ${isActive ? "border-[2px]" : ""}`
            }
            to="/"
          >
            All Memories
          </NavLink>
          {token && (
            <NavLink
              className={({ isActive }) =>
                `border p-2 font-semibold rounded-md text-black
             hover:bg-orange-500 active:bg-orange-700
             ${isActive ? "border-[2px]" : ""}`
              }
              to="/my-memories"
            >
              My Memories
            </NavLink>
          )}
        </div>
        <div>{token && <AvatarDropdown />}</div>
      </div>
      <div className="md:hidden flex flex-row-reverse items-center space-x-5">
        {token && (
          <div className="ml-3">
            <AvatarDropdown />
          </div>
        )}
        <DropdownMenu modal={true} onOpenChang={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
          <DropdownMenuTrigger className="outline-none">
            <i className="fa-solid fa-bars text-2xl p-2 text-black"></i>
          </DropdownMenuTrigger>
          <DropdownMenuContent align="end" className="text-center">
            <DropdownMenuItem
              onClick={() => navigate("/register-login")}
              className="px-5 py-1 "
              disabled={token}
            >
              <Plus className="mr-3" />
              Register or Login
            </DropdownMenuItem>
            <DropdownMenuSeparator />
            <DropdownMenuItem
              onClick={() => navigate("/")}
              className="px-5 py-1 "
            >
              <Users className="mr-3" />
              All Memories
            </DropdownMenuItem>
            <DropdownMenuSeparator />
            <DropdownMenuItem
              onClick={() => navigate("/my-memories")}
              className="px-5 py-1"
              disabled={!token}
            >
              <User className="mr-3" />
              My Memories
            </DropdownMenuItem>
            <DropdownMenuSeparator />
          </DropdownMenuContent>
        </DropdownMenu>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
});

export default Header;


Form component where I'm logging in and then navigating the user to a new page if login is successful.
import { Tabs, TabsContent, TabsList, TabsTrigger } from "@/components/ui/tabs";
import { registerUser, loginUser } from "@/features/userSlice";
import { useToasts } from "@/utils/useToastHook";
import { unwrapResult } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Footer } from "../exporter";
import { useState } from "react";

const RegisterAndLoginForm = ({
  name,
  loginForm,
  setLoginForm,
}) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const showToast = useToasts();

  const handleLoginInput = (e) => {
    setLoginForm({ ...loginForm, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

****************************** Handling login and then navigating to new page**********************
  const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
      try {
        const actionResult = await dispatch(loginUser(loginForm)).unwrap();
        const result = unwrapResult(actionResult);
        showToast("bg-green-700", "Success", "Login successfully.");
        localStorage.setItem("token", actionResult.data.accessToken)
        navigate("/my-memories");
        
      } catch (error) {
        showToast("bg-red-700", "Error", error.errorMessage);
      }
  };
****************************************************************************************************

  return (
    <main className="bg-transparent_bg w-full flex flex-col items-center box-border rounded-md">
      <form
        className="w-full text-center space-y-3 p-2 box-border"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <h3 className="font-extrabold text-foreground text-xl bg-slate-500 py-2 rounded-md tracking-widest">
          {name}
        </h3>
        <label className="form__label" htmlFor="username">Username: </label>
        <input
          id="username"
          className="input"
          type="text"
          placeholder="username"
          name="username"
          value={loginForm.username}
          onChange={handleLoginInput}
          required
          pattern="^[^\d]*$"
          title="name can not contains numbers"
        />
        <label className="form__label" htmlFor="password">Password: </label>
        <input
          id="password"
          className="input"
          type="password"
          placeholder="password"
          name="password"
          value={loginForm.password}
          onChange={handleLoginInput}
          required
        />

        <div className="flex justify-center gap-5 py-1 box-border">
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="bg-blue-400 w-24 px-3 py-2 rounded-md hover:bg-blue-500 active:bg-blue-600 text-white tracking-widest"
          >
            {name}
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </main>
  );
};

const LoginAndRegister = () => {
  const [loginForm, setLoginForm] = useState({username: "", password: ""});

  return (
    <>
      <div className="w-[80%] grid m-auto grid-cols-12 gap-1">
        <div className="md:col-span-6 col-span-12 md:text-center md:m-0 m-auto">
          <Tabs defaultValue="register" className="md:w-auto p-1">
            <TabsList className="w-full">
              <TabsTrigger value="register" className="w-[50%]">
                Register
              </TabsTrigger>
              <TabsTrigger value="login" className="w-[50%]">
                Login
              </TabsTrigger>
            </TabsList>
            <TabsContent value="register" className="border rounded-md">
              <RegisterAndLoginForm
                name={"Register"}
              />
            </TabsContent>
            <TabsContent value="login" className="border rounded-md">
              <RegisterAndLoginForm
                name={"Login"}
                loginForm={loginForm}
                setLoginForm={setLoginForm}
              />
            </TabsContent>
          </Tabs>
        </div>
        <div className=" max-h-[680px] md:col-span-6 overflow-hidden rounded-lg relative md:block hidden">
          <img src="login-hero.jpg" alt="login-hero" className="object-cover rounded-lg" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default LoginAndRegister;


I'm using react-router-dom v6 and the Layout component is as follow:
const Layout = () => {
  const [headerHeight, setHeaderHeight] = useState(0);
  const headerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (headerRef) {
      const height = headerRef.current.offsetHeight;
      if (height) {
        setHeaderHeight(height);
      }
    }
  }, [headerRef.current]);

  return (
    <>
      <Header ref={headerRef} />
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <div className="max-w-[1484px] flex flex-col items-center m-auto">
          <MemoriesHeader />
          <Outlet context={[headerHeight]} />
        </div>
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;

I tried re-rendering the header component using a state and setting it to false and true according to conditions but that didn't work either.

LocalStorage is non-reactive, updating localStorage won't trigger React to do anything. Store the token value in a React state and update it so React can, well..., react to the state update and rerender UI accordingly.

It works when I store the token in the redux state and fetch it for conditional rendering, but if I refresh the page the state is lost and the login doesn't persist.

You can initialize state from localStorage, and persist state updates to localStorage.

don't you need to put that in a useEffect?
something like
 const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY_TOKEN = 'token';

  const [token, setToken] = useState(() => {
    const storedToken = localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY_TOKEN);
    return storedToken !== null ? JSON.parse(storedToken) : null;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY_TOKEN, JSON.stringify(token));
  }, [token]);


Can you elaborate where? I'm confused. I'm setting the token in local storage in the section I've highlighted with Handling login and then navigating to new page

I guess whichever component you are using token to conditionally show buttons.
